# ATmega328 is not recognized by software

Tags: atmega328

I installed the required drivers for the board. But I cannot still upload a program to the board. It says that

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:00:53
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

```
     System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : usb
     Using Programmer              : stk500v2
```

avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb" (0x03eb:0x2104)

avrdude done.  Thank you.

An error occurred while uploading the sketch

Comment: Please explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish. The error indicates you're doing either an **Upload Using Programmer** or **Burn Bootloader** rather than a standard upload over serial. Turn on **File > Preferences > Show verbose output during: > upload**, do an upload, when it fails you will see a button on the right side of the orange bar "Copy error messages". Click that button. Edit your question and paste in the full verbose upload output.

Answer (score 1):

Can be many causes since you did not provide more info (like what circuit, what application). But in general:

- Wrong software installation
- Try another similar chip/device, maybe this one is broken
- Is it recognized by USB at all?
- Bad USB cable
- Did you select the right board in the IDE (Arduino IDE?)

Possible solution:

- Reinstall IDE
- Change chip
- Change Arduino
- Use different cable

Comment: It was not recognized at all. The error message is
avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:00:53
Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
Using Port                    : usb
Using Programmer              : stk500v2
avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb" (0x03eb:0x2104)
avrdude done.  Thank you.
An error occurred while uploading the sketch

Comment: In that case, try reinstalling the software, checking the USB (system) software, check if other avr's work, or check on another computer.